# C# connect to Oracle database using Wallet

Tags: c#, .net, oracle-wallet

I am building an app that connects to several Oracle databases.  I have no problem connecting to databases on our internal network, but I need to connect to one on that is hosted on the Oracle Cloud.  In SQL Developer the connection is made using an Oracle Wallet, but I have literally no idea how to utilize the wallet in C#.  An example would be really appreciated.

****Edit

I have at least got it to recognise my TNS entries, but I have hit a problem that I can make no progress on.  Here is my code;

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

class GetSchemaSample
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string constr = "User Id=/; Data Source=mytns;";
        string ProviderName = "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client";

        DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ProviderName);

        using (DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection())
        {
            try
            {
                conn.ConnectionString = constr;
                conn.Open();

                DataTable dtSchema = conn.GetSchema();
                dtSchema.WriteXml(ProviderName + "_Schema.xml");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And added this to my App.config;

```
  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <settings>
        <setting name="WALLET_LOCATION" value="c:\Oracle" />
        <setting name="SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE" value="true" />
      </settings>
    </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

The error I am encountering is;

```
The path is not of a legal form.
   at System.IO.Path.LegacyNormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength, Boolean expandShortPaths)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPathInternal(String path)
   at System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(String path)
   at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.StartRaisingEvents()
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.CreateSEPSFileWatcher(String walletPath, String walletFile)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.InitializeSEPSCredentials()
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Initialize(ConnectionString cs, OracleConnection con)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.GetPM(ConnectionString cs, OracleConnection con, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, Boolean& bAuthenticated, Boolean& newPM)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at GetSchemaSample.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\peter.holliday\source\repos\OACTesting\Connection1.cs:line 39
```

I have tried updating app.config WALLET_LOCATION entry in every way I can think of and also the sqlnet.ora file in the wallet (I assume this is a red herring as app.config seems to indicate overriding that), but I can't get past this error.  Even a pointer to how I can see what the value of "String walletFile" variable referred to in the error is would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you have [examples](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/tree/master/samples/autonomous-db)

---

### Managed Assemby/Driver

1. With managed assemby you have 2 options:

First option:

- put 2 files (sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora) from Wallet.zip to your executable path (bin/Debug)
- edit sqlnet.ora and change 'DIRECTORY' variable

```
WALLET_LOCATION=(SOURCE=(METHOD=file)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=<PATH_TO_WALLET_DIRECTORY>)))
```

Second option:

- add XML to your app.config

```
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <settings>
      <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="PATH_TO_WALLET_DIRECTORY"/>
      <setting name="Wallet_Location" value="PATH_TO_WALLET_DIRECTORY"/>  
    </settings>
  </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

---

### Unmanaged Assemby/Driver

- put 2 files (sqlnet.ora, tnsnames.ora) from Wallet.zip to your executable path (bin/Debug)
- edit sqlnet.ora and change 'DIRECTORY' variable (same as manged driver, option first)

---

### Connecting to DB

```
public static OracleConnection TakeMeToTheClouds()
{
    var user = "admin";
    var password = "YOUR PASSWORD";
    var ds = "THIS YOU FIND IN 'tnsnames.ora' FILE";

    var connectionString = $"User Id={user};Password={password};Data Source={ds};";
    return new OracleConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Comment: what about ODP.NET CORE ? How to enable .net core application? I am facing invalid user id or password issue when accessing wallet in asp.net core application.

Comment: You have to put `<setting name="SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE" value="true"/>` in the .config file settings too.

Comment: You saved me! The managed one worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't working for me, the answer shows how to connect using username/password & tnsnames rather than via the wallet credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this issue when the alias used in the wallet does not have a matching entry in the `tnsnames.ora` file.

It is worth checking that the datasource `mytns` does indeed exist in `tnsnames.ora`, and that in your wallet, the name of the entry matches the tns name, so in this case `mytns`.

Answer (score 0):

### Connecting to Oracle using an Oracle Wallet as credentials:

**C#**

```
//Install Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core NuGet Package  
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source=SCOTT; User ID=/");
conn.Open();
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
SCOTT =
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS =
(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.100)(PORT = 1521)
))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = MY_SERVICE)))
```

**sqlnet.ora**

```
wallet_location = (source = (method = file)
  (method_data=(directory = C:\scott_wallet))
)
SQLNET.WALLET_OVERRIDE=TRUE
```

**wallet creation:**

```
mkstore -wrl scott_wallet -create
mkstore -wrl scott_wallet -createCredential SCOTT SCOTT
```