# Not able to connect to Oracle DB through Wallet from C#

Tags: oracle

I am trying to connect to the Vendor's database through the Wallet. For that, the vendor has provided a wallet zip files which contains two files (one .ora file and one .sso file) . The zip file contains tnsnames.ora and cwallet.sso

First, I installed the Oracle client version 19.0 Home1 which has created a file called sqlnet.ora automatically. I copied the file tnsnames.ora to the same folder where sqlnet.ora created, and tried different wasys to connect the database, but every attempt failed. I tried to implement in similar way which is explained in this link, but getting errors that "TNS:Lost contact", "TNS:Could not resolved the connect identifier specified".

I tried the solution which specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716361/c-sharp-connect-to-oracle-database-using-wallet), but ended up in error. Finally, the error now is "Connection failed because target host or object does not exist". The connection details are specified in tnsnames. ora that contains the service name and host name. I have added the Wallet location in sqlnet.ora file and also the following code:

```
SSL_CLIENT_AUTHENTICATION = FALSE
SSL_VERSION = 1.2
SSL_CIPHER_SUITES = (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA)
SSL_SERVER_DN_MATCH = ON
```

The connection code in C# is below:

```
            //string strCon = "User Id =XXXX;Password=XXXXXXX;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXXXX)(PORT=2460))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX))" +
        //    "(SECURITY=(SSL_SERVER_CERT_DN='C=US,ST=Washington,L=Seattle,O=Amazon.com,OU=RDS,CN=mcsldb01.ckc6ued9hacf.ap-south1.rds.amazonaws.com')));";

        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(strCon))
        //using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(@"Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=XXXXXXXX)(PORT=2460)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=XXXX)));User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXXXXXX;"))
        //using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(cntn))
        {
            using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                try
                {
                    //TNS_ADMIN and wallet directory entries can be entered in the app.config file.

                    con.Open();

                    Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to Oracle Autonomous Database");

                    //Retrieve database version info
                    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT BANNER FROM V$VERSION";
                    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    reader.Read();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected to " + reader.GetString(0));
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Please suggest any solution. Where I am going wrong?  Not able to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, it might have been a connection wallet not an SSL wallet that has been provided, ie, just a mechanism of hiding the username and password. If that is the case, the connection would look something like:

```
new OracleConnection(@"Data Source=NAME_IN_TNSNAMES;User Id=/"))
```

where NAME_IN_TNSNAMES maps to the entry in the tnsnames.ora file.

Examples of that (from a SQL Plus perspective) here

https://connor-mcdonald.com/2015/09/21/connection-shortcuts-with-a-wallet/

Comment: It is SSL Wallet only. Now the error is bit different after made several attempts. Now the error is "SSL Failure in Parsing Wallet location". I tried to implement the solution [https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/41843194.html](here), but not understood on the certificate mentioned. Should this certificate be provided by the vendor?